# Linux Pam authentication by answering to a challenge

Tags: linux, authentication, pam, pluggable, challenge-response

I am trying to find a module that can help to ask a question to end an authentication. for example when I connect in ssh, the module ask me to resolve a equation or to answer to a question.

Comment: solved, i wrote it myself.